# How to Display Custom AlertDailog Box inside Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: android-layout, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-service, receiver

**I create custom layout which i want to use inside broadcast receiver, but `getLayoutInflater()` not work inside receiver**

inside onreceiver method i call  **startAlaram(context,intent)**

```
private void startAlaram(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout_notification, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(context,);
        builder.setTitle("Get Reminder");
        builder.setMessage("Alert ALert");
        builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
        builder.setView(view);
        final AlertDialog  dialog=builder.create();
        TextView not_txt_title,not_txt_desc,not_txt_callfor,not_txt_name;
        ImageView img1;
        not_txt_title = view.findViewById( R.id.not_txt_title );
        not_txt_desc = view.findViewById( R.id.not_txt_desc );
        not_txt_callfor = view.findViewById( R.id.not_txt_callfor );
        not_txt_name = view.findViewById( R.id.not_txt_name );
        img1 = view.findViewById( R.id.img1);

        not_txt_title.setText(rTitle);
        not_txt_desc.setText(rDesc);
        not_txt_callfor.setText(rCallFor);
        not_txt_name.setText(rName);
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a transparent activity with AlertDialog.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `void` for your `AlertDialog`.

```
private void alert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        //... your alert stuff

    }
```

Show your `AlertDialog` in your `Receiver`

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        alert();

    }
```

Comment: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity. this error caused because i use inside receiver.

Comment: @CodeInsideCofee You can create a void where you show the AlertDialog and instead of context you use *this*. Then you call the void in your Receiver.

Comment: @CodeInsideCofee What does  this mean? Any Errors?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: @Jakob, create dialog like this `AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light);`

Answer (score -2):

This is very Simple.

```
private void showDialog(){
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View deleteDialogView = factory.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);
    final AlertDialog deleteDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    deleteDialog.setView(deleteDialogView);
    deleteDialogView.findViewById(R.id.yes).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {    
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //your business logic 
            deleteDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    deleteDialogView.findViewById(R.id.no).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {    
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            deleteDialog.dismiss();    
        }
    });

    deleteDialog.show();
}
```

*** you have to register/unregister your broadcast.**

```
registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.mybroadcast"));
unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
```

**Your Broadcast code is like this.**

```
Broadcast mReceiver = new Broadcast(){

@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         showDialog()
    }

}
```

Comment: Dear Friend You Simple Solution Not Work inside receiver.

Comment: 1. /*remove this*/ builder.setView(view); .      2. 
        final AlertDialog  dialog=builder.create();      3.   Add this  dialog.setView(view);